# How to target h1 in div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm just making a mock website trying to learn to code and I'm having problems targeting h1 element in the divs. Another issue is that my banner is flowing further right than the top black menu bar causing the user to have to scroll right. I don't understand why this is. Would love all the help! Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title> Sankyeat Kumar | Web Developer </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></div>
        <div><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1> Web Developer</h1>
            <h4>London Based Web Developer For hire</h4>
        </div>          
    </div>



    <h2> Services </h2>




</body>



</html>


body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

#menu {
display:flex;
background-color: black;
max-height:50px;
max-width:100%;

}

#menu div {
margin: 0 auto;
color: ##678F99;
padding:10px;
}

#menu div a {
color:white;    
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#menu div a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

#banner {
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
background-image: url('images/mountains.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}

#heading {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
{

 #banner #heading h1 {
 color: white;

 }


}
```

Comment: Check your brackets. You have more opening ones than closing. I think that is the reason your H1 is not responding. The bracket above should be } not {.

Answer (score 1):

```
for targeting h1 you can use this-
you had a mistake on closing tag of css #heading

#banner {
  width:100%;
 /*100vw is getting a bit larger than screen because scrool bar on the right racking a little space from your screen*/

  width:calc(100vw - 17px);
 /* you can use this also. it minuses the scrolls width from screen width.*/
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

#menu {
display:flex;
background-color: black;
max-height:50px;
max-width:100%;

}

#menu div {
margin: 0 auto;
color: ##678F99;
padding:10px;
}

#menu div a {
color:white;    
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#menu div a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

#banner {
height:100vh;
width:100%;
width:calc(100vw - 17px);
background-image: url('images/mountains.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}

#heading {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

 #banner #heading h1 {
 color: red;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title> Sankyeat Kumar | Web Developer </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></div>
        <div><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1> Web Developer</h1>
            <h4>London Based Web Developer For hire</h4>
        </div>          
    </div>



    <h2> Services </h2>




</body>



</html>
```

Comment: I agree with this.  Fix the brace } and change width to 100% should do it.  The calc part was a nice touch, but be careful if you choose that route instead, older IE sometimes doesn't play well, if that matters to you.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! That worked perfectly :) I used with:100% but I still don't understand why you take off the 17px in the second route. Would really appreciate if someone could explain that to me.

Comment: The 17px is the size of the scrollbar.  Basically, VW takes up 100% of the viewport and the space that the scrollbar takes up is added onto that.  It's kind of tricky to explain, but the -17px is to offset the width of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target `h1` elements inside a `div` you can use the following:

```
div > h1 {
  //css goes here
}
```

This will target elements that are direct children of a `<div>`